# Automatically collapse regions when code file is closed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When I open up a C# file in Visual Studio (but *not* when I switch to its tab after its already opened), I want a "clean slate" for editing.  My idea of a clean slate is that all the `#region`s are collapsed.  I want that collapsing to occur when the code file is closed because, when I open the file for editing, I don't want the Undo history cluttered with `Collapse Region` actions.

My search revealed a Visual Studio extension called [I Hate #Regions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shanewho.IHateRegions) for the opposite purpose.  But I love `region`s!  Well, I love *collapsed* `#region`s.  Is there a Visual Studio extension for me?

Comment: Does [Collapse/expand all regions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/35657) help?

Comment: Is the Tools/Options/.../Enter Outlining Mode on File Open what you are looking for? Open Options and search for Outlining. Hope that's it.

Comment: @HABO Not if it requires manually executing a command. I open & close files quite often, so I want it to be automatic.

Comment: @SimonWilson That's just basic outlining support. It's already checked by default. Unchecking it does the opposite of what I'm asking for here.